# How would i display images in HTML using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show the images that are stored in "appendReturnedImages(data)" function. But I gets error and it cannot display the images. The format of images should be follow my HTML.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-5 single-top">   
    <ul id="etalage">

        <li>
            <img class="etalage_thumb_image img-responsive" src="images/si1.jpg" alt="" >
            <img class="etalage_source_image img-responsive" src="images/s2.jpg" alt="" >
        </li>
        <li>
            <img class="etalage_thumb_image img-responsive" src="images/si2.jpg" alt=""  >

        </li>
        <li>
            <img class="etalage_thumb_image img-responsive" src="images/si3.jpg"  alt="" >

        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 function appendReturnedImages(data) {


      var $html = $();

        $.each(data.images, function(index, element) {

       $html = $html.add($("<img/>", {

    height: 200,

    //width: 200, // uncomment this if you need to set width as well

    css: {

        'max-width': 200

    },

    src: element
     }));

$("#etalage").append($html);    
        });


          }
```

Javascript part  that sets the height and width

```
$('#etalage').etalage({
                thumb_image_width: 300,
                thumb_image_height: 400,
                source_image_width: 900,
                source_image_height: 1200,
                show_hint: true,
                click_callback: function(image_anchor, instance_id){
                    //alert('Callback example:\nYou clicked on an image with the anchor: "'+image_anchor+'"\n(in Etalage instance: "'+instance_id+'")');
                }
            });
```

Comment: Does the code you provided not work?

Comment: Does it give an error?  Check the developer console.

Comment: Actually i know the problem. my appendImages function appends images in div but i have to append in li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try creating an `li` element and append the images to it and then append the `li` element to your `ul`.

```
function appendReturnedImages(data) {
  var $html = $();
    $.each(data.images, function(index, element) {
   $html = $html.add($("<img/>", {
   height: 200,
//width: 200, // uncomment this if you need to set width as well
   css: {
    'max-width': 200
   },
   src: element
  }));
    $("#etalage").append($('<li/>').append($html));    
    });
  }
```

**EDIT**

I have added an edit for adding `li` elements for each image

```
function appendReturnedImages(data) {
  var $html = $();
    $.each(data.images, function(index, element) {
   $html = $html.add($("<img/>", {
   height: 200,
//width: 200, // uncomment this if you need to set width as well
   css: {
    'max-width': 200
   },
   src: element
  }));
    var $li = $('<li/>');
    $li.append($html[index]);
    $("#etalage").append($li);
    });
  }
```